# What does 'Ibid' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Someone I know got a interview call letter part of which read as this:

> .. you are requested to appear for the ibid interview ..

What does *ibid* mean in this context?

Comment: It says in the dictionary that *ibid* is the abbreviation for *ibidem*, which is an adverb. In the sentence, the word is used as an adjective. Maybe it's a different word?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe that in this case it means the person who wrote the letter does not know the proper usage of *ibid.*.  The proper usage of *ibid.* is in a bibliography or footnote to refer to the previous citation.

From the context, I would assume that the writer of the letter mentions the interview in a prior sentence, and now is trying to recall the same information.

For example:

> We will be interviewing you on our show "Brightly Colored Morning Extravaganza."
>   You are requested to appear for *ibid* interview on Thursday at 7 AM.

Unfortunately, this seems to be the work of a pseudo-intellectual.  I know this because, as the adage goes, it takes one to know one!

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this, but will hear what others have to say.

Comment: That seems quite reasonable.

Comment: maybe the company is called iBid?

Answer (score 5):

*Ibid.* is an abbreviation for the Latin word *ibidem*, which means “in the same place”.  It's commonly used in endnote/footnote citations, where it means “The information cited came from the same book as the previous citation.“

It's unusual (and, I think, ungrammatical) to use *ibid* as an adjective, but in this context, I'd assume the writer intended it to mean “above-mentioned” or “aforementioned”.  That is, your quotation is referring to an interview which the writer had described slightly earlier in the letter.

Comment: Thanks!  I left out the actual Latin definition from my answer.  (I would feel wrong editing it in now!)

Answer (score 3):

Going out on a limb, I see someone who tried to replace the typical Indian-English use of "the same" or "same" by something they thought was "more proper" English.

As a result, they managed to create something that is not only ungrammatical, but also semantically puzzling.

I would have no problems understanding this line in an Indian-English context if it were written as:

> We have planned an interview [...] and you are requested to appear for the same.

Interestingly, this is why I am weary of questions asking for replacements of standard (localized) expression, like "what is better alternative for `do the needful`.

Someone looked up an alternative for "the same" and found "ibid.", which can indeed be an alternative *in some cases*.

Thinking it looked better than the "Indianism", they ended up mangling their sentence :)

Comment: "the same" is not just Anglo-Indian terminology - IIRC, there is a phrase in Anglican (CofE) liturgy which reads something like "and defend us in the same", and that certainly predates the introduction of English as a common-use language in India.

Comment: I'm certainly not saying it _originated_ in India, I have no idea about that. Its current day use is quite tell-tale InE, though. Actually, there are quite some modern InE expressions that are simply considered old-fashioned or even obsolete in AmE or BrE (thrice?).

Comment: This usage of "the same" is used in formal American English.

Comment: I recall seeing it, but I never saw it being used quite as often as I saw it in formal and informal InE :)

Comment: I agree that anaphoric "the same" evokes InE in a present-day context. However, the two quotes that come to mind are from the King James Version, Ps. 113:3, and from Bret Harte's "Plain Language from Truthful James."